# Apostrophe in Oracle xml DBMS_XMLDOM

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

Using PLSQL, I created a program that provides SEPA files (xml files). I am using DBMS_XMLDOM package. The problem is that apostrophes are displayed as '& apos;' in the xml file.

Here is a part of the program :

```
text_value := MyCursor.ndest -- this a cursor value from the database. Let's say a name (D'ASILVA)

-- displaying text_value I see the apostrophe.

child_ofchelement:= DBMS_XMLDOM.CREATEELEMENT(doc,'Nm');
node:=DBMS_XMLDOM.APPENDCHILD(parent_node,dbms_xmldom.makenode (child_ofchelement));
l_text := DBMS_XMLDOM.createTextnode(doc,trim(text_value));
node := DBMS_XMLDOM.appendchild (node,dbms_xmldom.makenode(l_text));
....
dbms_xmldom.writeToFile(doc,rep_pwd||'/'||l_outfile, 'UTF8'); -- write DOM into file
dbms_xmldom.freeDocument(doc);
```

The database is encoded ISO-8859-1.
Inside the table the value has the apostrophe, in the file it is replaced by & apos;

First, I tried to changed the encoding of the file :

```
dbms_xmldom.writeToFile(doc,rep_pwd||'/'||l_outfile, 'WE8ISO8859P1');
```

Good format but still the '& apos;'

Secondly I tried :

```
text_value := utl_i18n.unescape_reference(MyCursor.ndest);
```

Same problem.

It is more like it becomes '& apos;' inside the writeToFile.

is there a way to ask not to escape the apostrophe with & apos; ?

Can u help ?

Comment: That's XML standard, what else do you expect?

Comment: To expand on @WernfriedDomscheit comment. This is a [predefined entity reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-predefined-ent) without it your output would not be well-formed XML.

Comment: I cannot have the apostrophe ?

Comment: I have another xml sepa file that comes from another program, there is no & apos; but apostrophe

Comment: You are not enforced to escape apostrophe, e.g. `<topic>mlwacosmos' question</topic>` would be valid because text is not ambiguous. However for text like `<area>Switzerland < China</area>` you must escape `<`. Anyway, it is always permitted to escape predefined entities `<>'&"`, your application must be able to handle that.

Comment: You are right but I am not the one who escapes the apostrophe...it is maybe writeToFile. My question is : is there a way NOT to escape the apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your text in CDATA section:

```sql
DECLARE
    doc dbms_xmldom.domdocument;
    parent_node dbms_xmldom.domnode;
    child_ofchelement dbms_xmldom.domelement;
    node dbms_xmldom.domnode;
    --change element type
    l_text dbms_xmldom.DOMCDATASECTION;
    text_value varchar2( 32 ) := 'D''ASILVA';
    clobdoc clob;
BEGIN
    doc := dbms_xmldom.newDOMDocument();
    dbms_xmldom.setVersion(doc, '1.0');
    parent_node := dbms_xmldom.makenode( doc );

    child_ofchelement := DBMS_XMLDOM.CREATEELEMENT( doc, 'Nm' );
    node := DBMS_XMLDOM.APPENDCHILD( parent_node, dbms_xmldom.makenode ( child_ofchelement ) );

    --change element creation method
    l_text := DBMS_XMLDOM.CREATECDATASECTION( doc, trim( text_value ) );

    node := DBMS_XMLDOM.appendchild( node, dbms_xmldom.makenode( l_text ) );

    dbms_lob.createtemporary(clobdoc, false);
    DBMS_XMLDOM.writeToClob(doc,clobdoc);
    dbms_output.put_line( clobdoc );

    dbms_xmldom.freeDocument(doc);
END;
```